# preg_match_all to get all occurrences of a string

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to find offset of all occurrences with preg_match_all

e.g.

```
$haystack = 'aaaab';
$needle = 'aa';

preg_match_all('/' . $needle . '/', $haystack, $matches);
```

$matches is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

It returns offset of first and second group of aa ("aa" "aa" "b") from the haystack, while I am expecting it to return "aa" starting at index 1 as well.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Is there a way I can fix the regex or use some other function (which accepts regex) to get this done?

PS: I know strpos which can do this, but I have few more things to search for hence will go with preg_match_all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change your needle expression to use an assertion.  This will prevent the 2nd `a` from being eaten by the regular expression engine:

```
$needle = 'a(?=a)';
```